# Tkinter button's commands while button is inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI application in Tkinter and I structured my program using an OOP approach. I have created a tk.Tk() instance and a class that inherits from tk.Frame, takes the Tk() instance as parameter and I do the creation of the GUI and the logic behind it inside the class.

Inside the class I have created a canvas on which I have placed some widgets. One of my widgets is an entry and another is a button. The button's command should be a function which takes as an input parameter the **current** value of the entry(using Entry.get()) method and do something with it say print it on the screen.

This is some code in which I have recreated the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

class myClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.Widgets()

    def getVal(self, val):
        print("The value is: ", val)

    def Widgets(self):
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, bg='green')
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        entry = tk.Entry()
        button = tk.Button(text='pressme')
        button['command'] = lambda arg = entry.get() : self.getVal(arg)

        window = canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=entry)
        window2 = canvas.create_window(100, 200, window=button)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MyGUI")
classinstance = myClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Function 'getVal' from the class should print whatever the value of  argument is where  should be the **current** value from the GUI's entry. Problem is that my program only sees the initial value from this entry(which in this case is an empty string) and does not change it afterwards as I update the GUI at runtime.

Now I assume this is because in the **main**.py program the classinstance gets created with some default values before the application enters tkinter's mainloop() function and once in this looping function I cannot go back inside the class and change the values. Please help me correct this issue and explain to me how I could make my application so that the command of the button gets an updated version of the entry's value and not the initial one. 
Thank you for reading my post!

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote `lambda arg = entry.get() : self.getVal(arg)` instead of `lambda: self.getVal(entry.get())`? What gave you the idea that a default argument was necessary there?

Comment: I wanted to make the code clearer :D. I think I understand what the problem was. The lambda function was using the original value of 'arg' always. Thank you. How can I accept your solution?

Comment: You can't. You can write and accept your own answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aran-Fey pointed out the lambda function was using the original value of 'arg' always and not changing it. In order for this to work entry.get() method should be used and not a default argument:

```
lambda: self.getVal(entry.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was located in the function of the button, because `lambda arg = entry.get()` imports `arg` only when the button is created.
Then, when the button is pressed, the lambda transfers the value of `arg` obtained at the beginning to the function, without re-importing it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class myClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.Widgets()

    def getVal(self, val):
        print("The value is: ", val)

    def Widgets(self):
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, bg='green')
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        var = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = var)
        button = tk.Button(text='pressme')
        button['command'] = lambda: self.getVal(var.get())

        window = canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=entry)
        window2 = canvas.create_window(100, 200, window=button)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MyGUI")
classinstance = myClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```